# Table to point feature class using ModelBuilder of ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, point, table

I am trying to convert a table in a fGDB to a point feature class using ArcMap 10.8. I need to do this in the ModelBuilder .

The table has about 8000 records, containing X and Y coordinates and many other attributes. I need to create points from the X and Y coordinates that also contain all the other attributes. I know the following procedure: "file -> add date -> add xy Date". But this does not provide a result that I can include in my model.

Is there any way I can create a point feature from xy data in ModelBuilder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make Table View, where you can choose which fields to keep
2. Make XY Event Layer, create a temp point layer
3. Copy Features, make it permanent

[image]